# How to send email on custom multi field on JetBrains YouTrack?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, youtrack

How to send email on custom multi field change with Notification Templates on YouTrack ?

How to reproduce:

1 Add new field in project

[image]

[image]

2 Add user to custom field

3 Notification email to that user is not sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a saved search like `Field name: me` and share it with your users. After that, users will have to check that they want to receive notifications on that search in their user profiles.